# ASP.net proper login - logout classes - control login status

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, logout, login-control

Would you have any suggestions improvements for the below functions classes ?

Ok here how do i make a registered member login

```
    HttpCookie LoginInfo = new HttpCookie("LoginInfo");
    LoginInfo.Values["UserName"] = srUserName;
    LoginInfo.Values["Password"] = srPassword;
    LoginInfo.Values["selectedLanguage"] = srSelectedLanguage;
    Response.Cookies.Add(LoginInfo);
```

Here how do i check visitor is logged in or not

```
public static void controlOfLoginStatus()
{
    string srQuery = "";
    string srUserName = "";
    string srPassword = "";
    string srLang = "";

    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"] == null)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["LoginInfo"] != null)
        {
            try
            {
                srUserName = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["LoginInfo"]["UserName"].ToString();
                srPassword = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["LoginInfo"]["Password"].ToString();
                srLang = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["LoginInfo"]["selectedLanguage"].ToString();
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
        string srUserIdTemp = csPublicFunctions.ReturnUserIdUsernamePassword(srUserName, srPassword);
        if (srUserIdTemp == "0")
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("Login");
        }
        else
        {
            csPublicFunctions.insertIntoOnlineUsers(srUserIdTemp, HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID);
            HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"] = srUserIdTemp;
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["lang"] == null)
                HttpContext.Current.Session["lang"] = srLang;
        }
    }

    srQuery = "SELECT UserId " +
     " FROM BannedUsers" +
     " WHERE UserId = " + HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"].ToString();
    using (DataTable dtTemp = DbConnection.db_Select_DataTable(srQuery))
    {
        if (dtTemp.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("exit.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

Here how do i log-out

```
public static void exitLogout()
{
    string srQuery = "delete from OnlineUsers where UserId=" + HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"].ToString();
    DbConnection.db_Update_Delete_Query(srQuery);

    try
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session["UserId"] = "0";
        HttpContext.Current.Session.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
    }
    catch
    {

    }

    try
    {
        HttpCookie LoginInfo = new HttpCookie("LoginInfo");
        LoginInfo.Values["UserName"] = "21412zxcvzxc343245243vvc";
        LoginInfo.Values["Password"] = "21412zxcvzxc343245243vvc";
        LoginInfo.Values["selectedLanguage"] = "en";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(LoginInfo);
    }
    catch
    {            
    }
}
```

`csPublicFunctions.ReturnUserIdUsernamePassword` uses parametrized queries so no possible risk of SQL injection

Comment: You have possible SQL injection for your `UserID=x` where clauses.  Any time you use string concatenation for queries, you risk SQL injection if you're not escaping your values properly.  I wouldn't recommend storing the users username and password in a cookie, you could store an authorization token instead which doesn't have any personal identifiable information in it.  This question is probably better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com.  You also have try/catch, but catch every exception and do nothing, which is bad form as well.

Comment: @Matthew thanks for recommendation. Session userid variable always checked both as integer and valid before assigned. So no possibility unless they can hack server and change session.

Comment: It's probably a better habit to get into using prepared statements always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly recommend you using asp.net FormsAuthentication and built in Membership provider. The code will result much cleaner and standarized.

In your case I would use SqlMembershipProvider. Check this link

http://bensteinhauser.wordpress.com/2012/07/16/using-the-sqlmembershipprovider/

Below is a sample of login code

```
var authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, //version
    login.UserName, // user name
    DateTime.Now, //creation
    DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), //Expiration
    true, //Persistent
    userId);

    var encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
    Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket));
```

the logout is very simple

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```

And for checking if the user is logged in just

```
User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```